# Codeigniter and jQuery application security issue or paranoia?

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I write a application in php - CodeIgniter framework and JavaScript - jQuery and Bootstarp frameworks.
I like to implement a general 'edit in field' method, and I don't like to use any plugin so I use:

```
<div class='editField">
  <input name="<?=$value->id?>" data-t="table_name" data-n="field_name" data_func="update" value="$value->value"/>
</div>

<script>
$(function () {    
    $('.editField').on('focusout', 'input, select', function () {
        var dta = {
            't' : $(this).attr('data-t'),
            'n' : $(this).attr('data-n'),
            'i' : $(this).attr('name'),
            'val' : $(this).val()
        };
        var le = 'index.php/linkToUpdateController/'+$(this).attr('data-func');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: le,
            data: dta
        });
    }); 
});
</script>
```

and linkToUpdateController.php:

```
public function update() {
       $arr = array(
       $this->input('n') => $this->input('val')
    );

    $this->db->where('id', $this->i);
    $this->db->update($this->t, $arr);
}
```

I know that CodeIgniter activeRecords ->where() method is escaped automatically and produce safer query but I'm feel something strange about html5 'data-' declaration method, because I need to use real table name and field name and my method became so transparent.

So any appreciation, comment or clue regard this method security issues will be appreciated, but my intention is to use 'edit in field' method not to drop out.
Thank you!
Leo.

Comment: That seems like a bad idea. It would be possible to tamper with the data before sending it to the server, which could have unintended results.

Comment: I picture that but this is very general answer. Can help me if I set size attribute to input ?